# Calling/referencing a variable or function from another class C++ using given framework

Tags: c++

I've been struggling this past week to understand c++ pointers. I don't know if it is the framework that we have been given or just c++ itself, but this is what I'm struggling with:

I have a rubbish game as it stands, and I want to implement a feature that knocks the player back when colliding with a flower object.

I have a flower class for the flower object.(called EnemyFlower.cpp)

I have a player class for the human object. (called DemoBObject.cpp)

How can I reference a boolean that I have in the flower object from the human object. The boolean is true when there is a collision between the two.

I can only move the human whilst in the class DemoBObject, but I can only detect a collision in Enemy Flower, so I need to call the collision bool from enemy flower to DemoBObject.

I have tried simply calling it like I would in java (currently in the DemoBObject class)

```
bool collisionresult = EnemyFlower::collision
```

I have tried setting up a return function in the flower object:

```
 bool EnemyFlower::returncollision(){
    return collision;
}
```

and then tried referencing it from human object (DemoBObject):

```
bool collision = &EnemyFlower::returncollision;
```

All with various different iterations and changes.

```
TL:DR - I don't know how to point to a variable in one class from another class.
```

EnemyFlower.cpp - http://pastebin.com/LBCJcKwS
DemoBObject.cpp - http://pastebin.com/6v9J63Ux

Comment: What `EnemyFlower` is, a class or an object? Do you understand the difference between the two?

Comment: both EnemyFlower and DemoBObject are classes

Comment: If you want to reference a variable in a flower *object*, you need to have a flower *object*. In C++, objects are often referred to via *variables*. Do you have a variable of type `EnemyFlower`?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean, I'll post a link to my flower class
http://pastebin.com/LBCJcKwS             DemoBObject -  http://pastebin.com/6v9J63Ux

Comment: I wouldn't even know how to create a flower object, I first tried putting pointers in the top. I was told to do the whole  EnemyFlower::EnemyFlower(BaseEngine* pEngine, DisplayableObject* p)
 : DisplayableObject( pEngine )                                                    bit, in order to reference other classes but I don't really understand it, and it didn't work when I tried to add another one in demobobject, just caused loads of compile errors no matter how I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** point to a member variable in another class. This either breaks encapsulation (making the `private` of the variable obsolete, a *lie* to the reader of your code if you want to put it radical) or means that the variable was not `private` to begin with, i.e. that there was no encapsulation to begin with.

Chances are that you don't need pointers at all. C++ is not Java. **In Java, you deal with pointers much more than in C++.** Java only calls them "references", except in the class name of `NullPointerException`, which gives the truth away. Java references are also slightly less powerful and dangerous than C++ pointers, but principally they are the same feature.

In C++, references and pointers are different things. That's very important to understand when you are new to C++ and are coming from Java.

Let's look at this piece of code:

```
bool collision = &EnemyFlower::returncollision;
```

This seems like an attempt at setting up a [member function pointer](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html). I would not use function pointers here, they probably complicate issues.

A better design would be to move the entire collision-detection part outside of the classes. Colliding is neither a property of a player nor of a flower. Perhaps having coordinates or a position is a property of both. This would result in a function as follows:

```
bool FindCollision(DemoBObject const &player, Flower const &flower)
{
    // calculate collision using player.GetX(), player.GetY(), flower.GetCoords()
    // or something like that
    //
    // ...

    return collision;
}
```

This `FindCollision` function has two interesting aspects. First, it does not take pointers but references (not possible in Java). Second, it does not need to be in a class. In C++, you often make such functions free-standing. Again, this is not possible in Java, where you often have to artifically invent a class and give it a single static method.

If you insist that the collision be a state inside of a flower (as I said, not a good idea IMO), then do as follows: Make the collision flag a private bool member variable of `Flower`, and give the class a public member function returning a **copy** of that variable:

Flower.h:

```
class Flower
{
private:
    bool m_collision;
    // ...

public:
    bool GetCollision() const;
    // ...
};
```

Flower.cpp:

```
bool Flower::GetCollision() const
{
    return m_collision;
}
```

Notice that I used another feature not available in Java: I made the member function `const`. In C++, when a member function doesn't change an object, you make it `const` (a little simplified, but it's a good rule to start with). Also note that this still doesn't need a pointer at all.

You can then call this member function from the player class. Of course, this means that the player class needs a reference to an object (again, not a pointer!) of type `Flower`.

Now if your member variable is `static`, then I'm afraid that the whole class design must be redone from scratch. It would not work like that in Java, either, because it would mean that there is only *one* collision state shared by *all* flowers. That certainly doesn't make sense.

Comment: Good luck! Chances are the framework is simply very badly designed, in which case it's hard to use it in a clean way.

Comment: I've tried to call it in the DemoBObject class, though I'm not sure how.  
I tried:
    bool collision = Flower::GetCollision; 
which didn't seem to work, It wanted a & in front. So I did that but it's value was just constantly true when it should be false. Is there a specific way I need to call it in the DemoBObject class? Or am I just being really bad xD. I also kind of assumed that the m_ in front of the collision variable was still using the collision variable that I had created, and that I didn't have to assign m_collision to something new

Comment: Putting a `&` in front of a variable means to take its address as a pointer. It is unlikely that you ever wanted to do this, especially since you are new to C++ -- it should be rare even in expert code. So perhaps you compared the pointer itself to true or false, rather than the value pointed to (ignoring the compiler warning it may have produced :)).

Comment: I equated a new bool collision in the DemoBObject class to be equal to  the object: bool collision = Flower::GetCollision; When I try and compile and run it only lets me run my last successful build

Comment: I assume I just called it wrong, because I'm not exactly sure how you are supposed to call it :(

Comment: I think you should reduce the problem to the bare minimum. Delete everything you can until you end up with a very short program consisting of a few lines with a main() function which can be compiled and run and which still contains the same problem. Post that mini program then.

Comment: I tried making a program, though the way our uni taught us, was to make us install Visual Studio, then give us a folder with a project, so I really have no idea how to create one from scratch. Instead I made a duplicate and deleted everything I didn't need, but that caused loads of errors. The same problem I had as before kept coming up: 'Flower::GetCollision': function call missing argument list; use '&Flower::GetCollision' to create a pointer to member. All I had was two classes with the same thing as I tried before.

Comment: Class1.h: http://pastebin.com/n8yi9RRK     
Class2.h: http://pastebin.com/B1xgfrrV

Comment: Nono, I meant posting as a new question here at SO! :) And it must be compilable, of course. Meaning that we can copy & paste it in a text editor and compile and run it. In *one* file. With *no* additional modification of the code on our part. With the whole framework stuff, that's certainly hard, but you should replace the framework classes with small "fake" classes. In fact, by doing so you might find the error yourself because you isolate the code which causes it...

Comment: To be honest, I know so little about c++, to the extent where I don't even know if I am calling it correctly. I'm probably going to give up this whole project because it is just frustrating and doesn't work for me at all. Only our professor knows how to fix problems because it is his framework, and he hasn't actually taught us c++, just given us a framework with 2 labs on how to use it, and expects us to know how to use the damn thing. When there is a problem nobody knows how to fix it, it's only worth 40% of the module. I do thank you very much for the help as it has cleared a lot up...cont

Comment: about c++ that I didn't know before, and hopefully it is useful to others too!. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. But don't give up on C++ in general. Teaching C++ to newbies with a *framework of your own* is just a horrible idea to begin with. It's not your fault, just find a better lecturer! :)